# Best way to upload file using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, upload

what is the best way of handling file uploads using node js?
I want my user to upload a profile image, the uploader should have this functionality:
 -validated that the image should be at min 200 * 200
 -file must be only png, jpg, jpeg or gif
-and other stuff that an uploader should have (for example renaming the file before saving that and lots of other, you know)
So, what package do you suggest me to use? is it better to use package or native node js?

Comment: nodejs only:  http://www.componentix.com/blog/9/file-uploads-using-nodejs-now-for-real

Comment: check this out, it shows how to upload binary files using multer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8COHTGz2cc

Answer (score 2):

For handling file uploads, you need to handle the **multipart/form-data** which contain the file and its metadata.

You can roll your own solution by handling this part, but I suggest you to go for `Multer` until you really understand all the specifics as it can get quite tedious.

**[Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)** has abstracted everything for you and gives you a very simple middleware interface to act on the form-data quite easily.

You can also look at this blog post which explains file uploading in node via **multer** with example:
https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/

Comment: Thanks, I wil use that in my projects.

Comment: Sure, it was my pleasure

Comment: In case this helps future readers: this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46655323/4017749) provides fairly concise code for accomplishing this without dragging in Multer or its 28 dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses `EXPRESS` with `NodeJS` then
[express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) is the simple and most powerful node-package to upload file(s) on the server. There you'll find all the options and steps to use this package.

Comment: Tho it's very heavy, unpacked size 1.21MB